# Error Exporting disk to a Storage account -Both configured with private endpoints in the same Vnet

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-storage-account, azure-disk

I've deployed an ARM template, where I deployed a disk, a storage account, a vnet and a subnet, and have configured each of them for a private endpoint.

Following are some pieces of that:

for disk:
[image]

for storage account:
[image]

and configuring their private endpoints:
[image]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mw4j.png)

Doing this, will make the disk and storage account fall in the same vnet and I'll be able to export the disk from there.

I was using the Azure Cli to do the copy using the **az storage blob copy start** command.
I retrieved the key from the portal of the storage account and generated $sas for the disk to be exported.
now using the command gave the following error:
[image]

However the rules seemed to be fine.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and read about what's on-topic in the [help/on-topic]. SO is only for _programming_ questions. You might have better luck on [sf].